# C# Attributes : Using enum constants as input parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, access-control

I'm trying to implementing a new permission based access approach for my MVC application; We have several **Permission Group** and each group contains a list of **Permission**. for example we have `Invoices` permission group which contains `CreateInvoice,RemoveInvoice,etc` permission keys.

In this approach each mvc `Action` should requires a specific permission for execution. I'm trying to do this through CustomAttributes, something like this :

```
public class InvoiceController : Controller
    {
        [RequirePermission(Permissions.Invoices.CreateInvoice)]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

To make it easier for developers to remember different Permission Groups and Permission Keys I'm trying to create a pre-defined list of permissions that should be a combination of permission group and permission key. but due to restrictions applied to using attributes arguments in C#
I couldn't make it work yet. (**I don't want to make an extra large enumurator and put all permission keys in there**)

my last try was creating an enumerator for each permission group and then define permission keys as enum constants in there :

```
public class PermissionEnums
{
    [PermissionGroup(PermissionGroupCode.Invoice)]
    public enum Invoices
    {
        CreateInvoice = 1,
        UpdateInvoice = 2,
        RemoveInvoice = 3,
        ManageAttachments = 4
    }

    [PermissionGroup(PermissionGroupCode.UserAccounts)]
    public enum UserAccounts
    {
        Create = 1,
        ChangePassword = 2
    }
}
```

As you can see we have a combination of codes here, the permission group key specified using a `PermissionGroup` attribute and permission key's code specified as numeral code on each enum constant.

the RequirePermission attribute defined as below :

```
public class RequirePermissionAttribute : Attribute
{
    private Enum _Permission;

    public RequirePermissionAttribute(Enum Permission)
        : base()
    {
        _Permission = Permission;
    }
}
```

but the problem is that objects of type `Enum` could not be used as Attribute Arguments.

Any suggestion/idea is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution, the only thing needs to be changed is type of constructure parameter. instead of using `Enum` you have to use `object` :

```
public class RequirePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private object _Permission;

    public RequirePermissionAttribute(object Permission)
        : base()
    {
        _Permission = Permission;
    }
}
```

Here is the complete code :

```
/***************** Permission Groups And Keys *****************/
public static class Permissions
{
    [PermissionGroup(PermissionGroupCode.Invoice)]
    public enum Invoices
    {
        CreateInvoice = 1,
        UpdateInvoice = 2,
        RemoveInvoice = 3,
        ManageAttachments = 4
    }

    [PermissionGroup(PermissionGroupCode.UserAccounts)]
    public enum UserAccounts
    {
        Create = 1,
        ChangePassword = 2
    }
}

public enum PermissionGroupCode
{
    Invoice = 1,
    UserAccounts = 2,
    Members = 3
}

/***************** Attributes & ActionFilters *****************/

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Enum)]
public class PermissionGroupAttribute : Attribute
{
    private PermissionGroupCode _GroupCode;
    public PermissionGroupCode GroupCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _GroupCode;
        }
    }

    public PermissionGroupAttribute(PermissionGroupCode GroupCode)
    {
        _GroupCode = GroupCode;
    }
}


public class RequirePermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private object _RequiredPermission;

    public RequirePermissionAttribute(object RequiredPermission)
        : base()
    {
        _RequiredPermission = RequiredPermission;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var permissionGroupMetadata = (PermissionGroupAttribute)_RequiredPermission.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PermissionGroupAttribute), false)[0];

        var groupCode = permissionGroupMetadata.GroupCode;
        var permissionCode = Convert.ToInt32(_RequiredPermission);

        return HasPermission(currentUserId, groupCode, permissionCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats possible I tried to do your thing and failed :/ sorry.

Permissions on actions should be used with Authorize and you can make your own ovveride writing something like this:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public sealed class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        //Its a piece of code from my app you can modify it to suit your needs or use the base one
        if (!new CustomIdentity(httpContext.User.Identity.Name).IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext    filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);

     }

}
```

then on your action:

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "FE")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Documents");
}
```

however its still a string that you use and for it to work you need to combine it with Custom Role provider. Much hussle but worth it in my opinion.

Comment: yep, I've done that but my problem is not creating an attribute (ActionFilter attribute) to check user permissions. I just need a better way (than using plain string keys) to create predefined permission constants.

Comment: http://www.vivienchevallier.com/Articles/create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-that-accepts-parameters-of-type-enum  Try this.